# How to create unit test cases with closures

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have created unit test cases in My App, So far good. I am using **MVVM** in my project & I have API request which has `success & failure` `closures`. how can I make test cases for that.

What I tried:

```
var mockAPIService: MockApiService!

override func setUp() {
  super.setUp()
  mockAPIService = MockApiService()
  sut = PhotoListViewModel(apiService: mockAPIService)
}

func test_fetch_photo() {
  sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
    print("apiSuccessClouser") // This doesnot executes 
    XCTAssert(dataValue)
  }
}
```

But `print("apiSuccessClouser")` not executing.. I am just looking for make clouser work with Unit test.

Comment: Please share an outline of the code you want to test, not just your test code. It's not clear what you are trying to test, and any possible answers hinge on that.

Answer (score 2):

Store dataValue in some variable and use expectation to wait for your closure to execute and then test. Note: This example was written in swift 4

```
let yourExpectationName = expectation(description: "xyz")
var dataToAssert = [String]() //replace with you data type
sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
      dataToAssert = dataValue
      yourExpectationName.fulfill()
 }
    
waitForExpectations(timeout: 3) { (error) in //specify wait time in seconds
    XCTAssert(dataToAssert)
}
```

Comment: thanks.. `expectation` replaced with `XCTestExpectation` & it works. By the way can you please update answer how can we do it with *Quick/Nimble* ?

Answer (score 0):

apiSuccessClouser in MockApiService is a property of type closure `(()->Void?)?`.

In line  `sut.apiSuccessClouser = { ... }` you assign the the property apiSuccessClouser a closure but you never access this closure so that the `print("apiSuccessClouser")` to be executed.

to execute the print("apiSuccessClouser") you need to call the closure

```
sut.apiSuccessClouser?()
```

So refactor the test like:

```
func test_fetch_photo() {
  sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
  print("apiSuccessClouser") // This doesnot executes 
  XCTAssert(dataValue)
 }
sut.apiSuccessClouser?()
}
```

for more info: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

To test that kind of asynchronous code with vanilla XCTest, you'll need to use an [`XCTestExpectation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation).

```
func test_fetch_photo() {
  let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "photo is fetched")

  sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
    // I like to run the assertions directly inside of the async closure, that way
    // you don't need to have vars around to store the value in order to check it
    // afterwards
    XCTAssert(dataValue)

    expectation.fulfill()
  }

  sut.apiSuccessClouser?()

  // The timeout duration depends on what kind of async work the closure is doing,
  // here, because it's called directly, you probably don't need long.
  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
}
```

The assertions library [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) also offers a neat way to test asynchronous code.

```
func test_fetch_photo() {
  waitUntil { done in
    self.sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
      assert(dataValue).toNot(beNil())
      done()
    }

    self.sut.apiSuccessClouser?()
  }
}
```

Alongside `waitUntil`, Nimble also has a [`.toEventually` assertion](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/tree/2c6978e887d7caa8acc2cab7b38e89d4d63eafb6#asynchronous-expectations).

You asked about using [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick), too. Quick is a test *harness* library, it allows you to write tests in a different way, but it doesn't make a different in how you write the actual expectation.

```
describe("Name of your system under test") {
  it("does something asynchronously") {
    let sut = ...
    
    waitUntil { done in
      self.sut.apiSuccessClouser = { dataValue in
        assert(dataValue).toNot(beNil())
        done()
      }

      self.sut.apiSuccessClouser?()
    }
  }
}
```